# Group by specific and calculate total for dynamically added objects Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form in Angular 2 with fields that are dynamically added by the user. The Added object looks like this:

```
[ { "equipment_type_id": 1, "action": "added", "quantity": 3}]
```

The equipment type can be duplicated multiple times with different quantities, I need to group by equipment_type_id and calculate the totals using the quantity.

I have used the reduce function to group but am not sure how I can calculate the total rather than just add the quantity to the new object

```
var groups = this.inspection.equipments.reduce(function(obj,item){
  obj[item.equipment_type_id] = obj[item.equipment_type_id] || [];
  obj[item.equipment_type_id].push(item.quantity);
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Any help for this would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to check if an item of that type has already been added or not:

```
if (obj[item.equipment_type_id] == null)
```

If it has (i.e. the above if statement is false), then just add on the new quantity:

```
obj[item.equipment_type_id].quantity += item.quantity;
```

Here is an example below

```js
let equipments = [ 
  { "equipment_type_id": 1, "action": "added", "quantity": 3},
  { "equipment_type_id": 1, "action": "added", "quantity": 5},
  { "equipment_type_id": 2, "action": "added", "quantity": 4}
]

var groups = equipments.reduce(function(obj,item) {
  if (obj[item.equipment_type_id] == null) {
    obj[item.equipment_type_id] = item;
  } else {
    obj[item.equipment_type_id].quantity += item.quantity;
  }
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this using the following:

```
calcTotals(){
    var groups = this.inspection.equipments.reduce(function(obj,item){
      obj[item.equipment_type_id] = obj[item.equipment_type_id] || { equipment_type_id: item.equipment_type_id, total: 0};
      // Calculate total based on action
      var total = obj[item.equipment_type_id].total;
      if(item.action === 'added'){
        total = total + item.quantity;
      }else{
        total = total - item.quantity;
      };
      obj[item.equipment_type_id].total = total;
      return obj;
    }, {});
    return groups;
}
```